Tie row height to grid width
My grid can have cell content of varying heights, three cells in each row, the row height grows to match the tallest cell content, but should not drop below 1/3 of the grid width (basically meaning cells are either square or in portrait mode, but never in landscape mode).
I thought there would be a pure CSS way to achieve this, but so far I couldn't find it.
Is this doable with CSS?
(Plan B will be to use a ResizeObserver and propagate the current width into a custom css variable)
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>
  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>
  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>

  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>
  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>
  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>
</div>

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; // ? something like minmax(container-width / 3, 1fr)
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.cell {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


container-width / 3 - Isn't that just 33vw?

vw is the width of the browser window; but the grid (container) can have any other arbitrary width

Then your only option I think would be to wrap the grid in a div and use container units.

aspect-ratio:1 to the .cell elements

@TemaniAfif But would aspect-ratio: 1 not force a square? so they could not grow taller?

aspect-ratio is a weak declaration, element can get taller if they contain more content

@TemaniAfif Oh that's nice to know; will definitely try this out. Thanks for the hint.

You may give a try to containerquerie and  cqw units (width of the parent container ) , min-height:33.33cqw  should make an average square or grow taller .

https://caniuse.com/css-container-query-units
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_containment/Container_queries

exemple to test in your browser (tested only  in ff & chrome)


.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.cell {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 40px;
  min-height: calc(33.33cqw - 1em);
  /* removed the padding value */
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* for demo in fullsize snippet */

.grid {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>
  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>
  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>
  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>
  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>
  <div class="cell">...arbitrary content...</div>
</div>



